# Trying to align text under inline images using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my text under a line of 3 images using HTML/CSS. As 
soon as i remove my comments it aligns everything vertically.

```
<div class="inline">     
        <img class="rel" src="http://imgur.com/a/n2skT.png" alt="icon" />
        <!-- <p> This is a test</p> -->         
        <img class="rel" src="http://imgur.com/a/n2skT.png" alt="icon" />
        <!-- <p> This is a test</p> -->         
        <img class="rel" src="http://imgur.com/a/n2skT.png" alt="icon" />
        <!-- <p> This is a test</p> -->      
    </div>
```

See my example https://jsfiddle.net/gvrr25bk/1/

Thanks in advance!

Ivan

Comment: `<p />` are block-level elements by default and therefore always starts on a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could wrap each `img` with it's `p` inside a `div` and add `display:inline-block` to that `div` instead

```css
.inline {
    text-align: center;
}
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">     
            <div class="wrap">
            <img class="rel" src="http://imgur.com/a/n2skT.png" alt="icon" />
            <p> This is a test</p>        
            </div>
             <div class="wrap">
            <img class="rel" src="http://imgur.com/a/n2skT.png" alt="icon" />
            <p> This is a test</p>    
            </div>
             <div class="wrap">
            <img class="rel" src="http://imgur.com/a/n2skT.png" alt="icon" />
            <p> This is a test</p>  
             </div>
 </div>
```

see more here [CSS align](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) and here [CSS inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) or in general about css [CSS w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

about HTML blocks and inline elements see here [HTML Block and Inline Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

the idea to the solution i gave you is that if you want the image to stay together with it's text , you should put them in the same container separately. in that way they will always stay together as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much Mihai T. Do you perhaps know of a good informative tutorial i could follow somewhere?

Comment: i added some links in my answer, i don't know of any tutorial in which you can learn exactly what you want, but you need to learn from different places and then use that knowledge to achieve what you need